# p5: Using Sine wave in WEBGL to change y-axis

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I have some spheres that I want to move straight on the x axis with only their y-axis changing based on the sine wave (you know the up and down yo-yo pattern). It is pretty simple in 2d but for some reason, in WEBGL, the angle changes in the sin function is not working for `this.y`.

```js
let particles = [];
let quantity = 20;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(300, 300, WEBGL);

  for (let i = 0; i < quantity; i++) {
    let particle = new Particle();
    particles.push(particle);
  }
}

function draw() {
  background(15);
  orbitControl();
  directionalLight([255], createVector(0, 0, -1));
  translate(-width / 2, 0);

  particles.forEach(particle => {
    particle.update();
    particle.edges();
    particle.show();
  });
};


// particle.js
function Particle() {
  this.angle = 0;
  this.r = 10;
  this.x = random(width);
  this.y = sin(this.angle) * 200; // I am changing this angle later but it's not working
  this.z = random(-50, 50);
  this.pos = createVector(this.x, 0, 0);
  this.vel = createVector(2, this.y, 0);

  this.update = function() {
    this.pos.add(this.vel);
    this.vel.limit(4);
    this.angle += 3;
    // print(this.pos);
  }

  this.edges = function() {
    if (this.pos.x >= width) {
      this.pos.x = 0;
    }
  }

  this.show = function() {
    noStroke();
    push();
    translate(this.pos.x, this.pos.y, 0);
    sphere(this.r);
    pop();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.1/p5.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only call `sin` one time in the construtor. You probably meant to apply it to `this.y` on every frame based on `this.angle`, or some other incrementing value. Also, there are duplicate vectors; pick either an `x`/`y` pair or use a vector `x`/`y`, but not both.

```js
let particles = [];
let quantity = 20;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(300, 300, WEBGL);

  for (let i = 0; i < quantity; i++) {
    let particle = new Particle();
    particles.push(particle);
  }
}

function draw() {
  background(15);
  orbitControl();
  directionalLight([255], createVector(0, 0, -1));
  translate(-width / 2, 0);

  particles.forEach(particle => {
    particle.update();
    particle.edges();
    particle.show();
  });
};


// particle.js
function Particle() {
  this.angle = 0;
  this.r = 10;
  this.x = random(width);
  this.y = 0;

  this.update = function() {
    this.angle += 0.05;
    this.y = sin(this.angle) * 100;
  }

  this.edges = function() {
    if (this.x >= width) {
      this.x = 0;
    }
  }

  this.show = function() {
    noStroke();
    push();
    translate(this.x, this.y, 0);
    sphere(this.r);
    pop();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.6.0/p5.js"></script>
```